# The frontier of a set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category

I'm trying to prove that a certain set is dense in a metric space.
I have a metric space X, an open subspace $Y\subset X$ (same metric) and an open set $U\subset Y$ s.t $U$ is open and dense in $Y$. Moreover, X is Baire. I define $B=X\setminus \overline Y$ and tried proving that $U\cup B$ is dense in X.
Is the following proof correct?

$cl(U\cup B)=cl(U_n\cup(X\setminus cl(Y))=cl(U_n)\cup cl(X\setminus cl(Y))$

Now I claim that: $cl(X\setminus cl(Y))=(X\setminus cl(Y))\cup Fr(X\setminus cl(Y))=cl(X\setminus cl(Y))=(X\setminus (Y\cup Fr(Y))\cup (Fr(cl(Y)))=(X\setminus Y)$

and therefore $cl(U_n)\cup cl(X\setminus cl(Y))=Y\cup(X\setminus Y)=X$

Is it true that $Fr(Y)=Fr(cl(Y))$ - specifically in a metric Baire space?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not true. Take $X=\Bbb R$, endowed with the usual metric. It is a Baire space, but $\operatorname{Fr}(\Bbb Q)=\Bbb R$, whereas $\operatorname{Fr}\left(\overline{\Bbb Q}\right)=\emptyset$.

Comment: And in this specific case where $Y$ is open?

Comment: Not even then. If $Y=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, then $Y$ is open, but $\operatorname{Fr}(Y)=\{0\}$, whereas $\operatorname{Fr}\left(\overline Y\right)=\emptyset$.

Comment: Ok I see. What is the right approach to prove that such $U\cup B$ is dense? It's really tricky

Comment: Take $x\in X$. If $x\not\in\overline Y$, then $x\in B$; in particular, any open set containing $x$ intersects $B$. Otherwise, let $A$ be an open subset of $X$ to which $A$ belongs. Since $x\in\overline Y$, $A\cap Y\ne\emptyset$. And, since $A$ is an open subset of $X$, $A\cap Y$ is an open subset of $Y$. But then $(A\cap Y)\cap U\ne\emptyset$, since $U$ is dense in $Y$. So, I have proved that, in any case, $A\cap(B\cup U)\ne\emptyset$, and this proves that $B\cup U$ is dense in $X$.